# CAS 4 - How to retrieve LDAP attributes and get error 'PersonDirectoryPrincipalResolver failed to resolve principal'?

Tags: authentication, attributes, ldap, cas

Long story short, I use CAS4.0 to connect LDAP server. When I use mock data to test, it is successful to authenticate uid/password from LDAP server and retrieve data from `StubPersonAttributeDao`. then, I revise data from LDAP server, I failed in Authentication and get error `PersonDirectoryPrincipalResolver failed to resolve principal`. Anyone can help? the detailed story is as following:

I add `attributeRepository` in `deployerConfigContext.xml` to use mock data as following:

```
<bean id="attributeRepository" class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.StubPersonAttributeDao"
            p:backingMap-ref="attrRepoBackingMap" />

    <util:map id="attrRepoBackingMap">
        <entry key="uid" value="uid" />
        <entry key="eduPersonAffiliation" value="eduPersonAffiliation" /> 
        <entry key="groupMembership" value="groupMembership" />
    </util:map>
```

When running the code, I can successfully retrieve mock attribute eduPersonAffiliation and groupMembership when calling serviceValidate.

Then, I try to retrieve data from LDAP server to CAS, so I changed `attributeRepository` as  following:

```
 <bean id="attributeRepository" 
          class="org.jasig.cas.persondir.LdapPersonAttributeDao" 
          p:baseDN="dc=example,dc=com" 
          p:searchFilter="uid={0}" 
          p:searchControls-ref="searchControls" 
          p:connectionFactory-ref="connectionFactory" 
          p:resultAttributeMapping-ref="resultAttributeMap" 
          /> 

     <util:map id="resultAttributeMap"> 
       <entry key="uid" value="uid" /> 
       <entry key="mail" value="mail" /> 
       <entry key="cn" value="cn" /> 
     </util:map> 

     <bean id="searchControls" 
           class="javax.naming.directory.SearchControls" 
           p:searchScope="2" 
      />
```

I have `ldapAuthenticationHandler`as following:

```
<bean id="ldapAuthenticationHandler"
      class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.LdapAuthenticationHandler"
      p:principalIdAttribute="uid"
      c:authenticator-ref="authenticator">
    <property name="principalAttributeMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="uid" value="uid" />
            <entry key="mail" value="mail" />
            <entry key="cn" value="cn" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

but I an error as following, it authenticate successfully first, then gave an error to fail the authentication :
2016-05-18 15:02:44,979 INFO

```
[org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] - LdapAuthenticationHandler successfully authenticated newton+password
2016-05-18 15:02:44,985 ERROR [org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] - org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.PersonDirectoryPrincipalResolver@35ab1a4c failed to resolve principal from newton+password
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection is not open
    at org.ldaptive.DefaultConnectionFactory$DefaultConnection.getProviderConnection(DefaultConnectionFactory.java:272)
```

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Did you get this resolved?  I'm struggling with this; not getting an error because I don't have an attributeRepository.  I'm not getting any errors, just no attributes back.  The Apereo documentation seems to be maybe missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Your ldap authn handler is able to retrieve attributes without a principal repository. See http://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/installation/Configuring-Principal-Resolution.html#principalresolver-vs-authenticationhandler

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do this? I have authentication handler and principalAttributeMap with all the required attributes. How to populate this to an attributeRepository? If I am not defining an attributeRepository, its throwing an exception stating that attributeRepository is required. Plz help.